# Play .XM .MOD audio files in Delphi without DLLs

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe5

I want to play .XM or .MOD files in Delphi without using DLLs. I searched here and similar websites. Finally I found a good library (`BeRoXM.pas`) for doing this and it can do exactly what I want to do. (You can download it [here](http://bero.0ok.de/downloads/BeRoXM.zip))

But as I'm using Delphi XE5, I cannot compile the unit. The code is too old.

So how can I play those files?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

uFMOD enables you to play .xm soundtracks [chiptunes] from within your application easily.  By specifying parameters, you can play .xm files from disk, memory or resource.

http://www.delphibasics.info/home/delphibasicssnippets/ufmodexample-playxmfilesfromdiskmemoryorresource

Answer (score 2):

> Types of actual and formal var parameters must be identical

This is error E2033, [described by the documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/E2033_Types_of_actual_and_formal_var_parameters_must_be_identical_%28Delphi%29) as follows:

> For a variable parameter, the actual argument must be of the exact type of the formal parameter.

So the error is with a `var` parameter, and [`BeginThread`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.BeginThread) only has one: the final parameter. The library code is passing `ThreadID` for that `var` parameter and `ThreadID` which is declared as:

```
ThreadID: THandle;
```

But the `BeginThread` function expects a `TThreadID` (which is an alias for `LongWord`) for that parameter. The library code is completely bogus. A thread ID is categorically not a `THandle`.

In older versions of Delphi `THandle` was incorrectly declared as `LongWord`. Thankfully recent versions of Delphi fix that travesty by declaring it as `NativeUInt`, although I personally would prefer it to be declared as an untyped pointer as it is in the Windows header files.

Fix the `BeRoXM` library code by changing the type of `ThreadID` to `TThreadID`. Expect there to be more problems as you port this code to XE5.

Comment: 1) since that library compiled once, i'd expect that it was on Delphi RTL part to confuse THandle and TThreadID types (though I don't see why they should be separated more that all other kind of Windows handles, that boil down to DWORD in Win32, and the lib was last touched in 2009 before win64 Delphi)  2) since the development ended in 2009 I only can wonder if it is Unicode-aware. If not, and if the topicstarter is stopped by this - as you said - simple error, i'm afrai to imagine the journey to catch all pointers-related errors in a multithreading application...

Comment: @Arioch HANDLE has never been DWORD. The former is a pointer, the latter is a 32 bit uint.

Comment: Did it really matter for a program calling through the DLL boundary ? Maybe I should look into Win16 ear, dunno

Comment: @Arioch What are you talking about? Surely you recognise the compiler error?

Comment: I am taking about your calling bogus having different interpretations of DLL int32 type. As long as it was passed into stack according to stdcall convention, it did not matter if that was called int, uint, or ptr. // About compiler, I already told you, that assuming the library had ever compiled (I think it had), you should call the whole Delphi RTL bogus then

Comment: @Arioch There are no DLLs, it just a trivial compiler error. It's really not that hard to understand.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Thanks. I changed the type of `ThreadID` and it compiled successfully with no errors. But I think the thread never runs. I mean after changing that, it doesn't make any threads for playing audio files. I can run it but I can't play any files. (I couldn't play anything either when I deleted that line)

Comment: @Sky I believe that I answered the question that you asked

Comment: @Arioch'The I cannot for the life of me understand what you are talking about. The code that you did not download attempts to pass a `THandle` to a var parameter of type `TThreadID = LongWord` and that leads to a compiler error. There are no DLLs involved. There is no stdcall. There is just [E2033 Types of actual and formal var parameters must be identical](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/E2033_Types_of_actual_and_formal_var_parameters_must_be_identical_(Delphi))

Comment: @DavidHeffernan so you have to assume one of two options: either that library NEVER been compiled, or Delphi RTL contemporary to the library development did not make difference between TThreadId and THandle. I'm for the latter option. And then calling the library bogus for following RTL relaxed idea of types is somewhat an overstatement

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Okay thanks for your answer and could you please tell me what's the difference between `THandle` and `TThreadID`?

Comment: @Arioch A THandle is  a pointer and is something that can be passed to CloseHandle. A Thread ID is a 32 bit integer, something else altogether. Surely this is not news to you. And if so then you've just learnt something.

Comment: @Sky My last comment to Arioch does that. They are chalk and cheese. Older versions of the Delphi RTL defined `THandle` incorrectly which allowed the type abuse that this BeRoXM committed. Modern versions of Delphi fix that. I suspect there are many other problems with this library when compiled by XE5.

Comment: "THandle is a pointer" to what? Handle^ points to what exactly ? Outside of Windows internal it is just - in win32 API - a data chunk 32 bits in size. There is no practical difference. Though it probably appeared in Win64 so they changed the declaration in RTL.

Comment: @sky I suspect mixing those type would make impossible compilation of the same sources for both win32 and win64 targets. It was not an issue in 2009 ( Delphi could not make Win64 code before XE2, and FreePascal probably was not considered by the library maker ), but later (probably in XE2) Embarcadero changed RTL to make those types different and ensure Win32/Win64 source-level compatibility.

Comment: @Arioch The fact that the external client cannot de-reference it does not make it less of a pointer. Read the Windows header files, or the Windows Data Types topic on MSDN if you want to learn something. What's more, even if two things are stored in the same sized variable, that does not make them interchangeable. Or do you believe that a ^Double is the same as a ^Integer? If you want to continue storing TIDs and PIDs in THandle then you are very foolish.

Comment: @Arioch'The Your argument that `THandle` is not a pointer is quaint. Instead of saying "Handle^ points to what exactly?" write it like this, "Poitner^ points to what exactly?" You've just proved that a `Pointer` is not a pointer. I suggest that you read this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751.aspx#HANDLE

Comment: Exactly it does. Any data has a sense only within the interpreter. If for Windows routines that is direct pointer - fine. Though I hope it is not, or at least it is checked 1st. But outside of the interpreter - on a client side of DLLs - it is just an abstract[ed] 32-bits token.  Of course they are not interchangeable. Even X and Y variables are not interchangeable though both are integer. However that is not enough to call typesystem of pre-XE2 Delphi "bogus". If it was - you would be struck by the bogusness and knew it already.

Comment: Then  HWND and HDLL and HResource and HBitmap are not interchangeable also. Should Delphi stop deriving those types from THandle to be les bogus ?

Comment: @Arioch'The I always knew that `THandle` was declared incorrectly. Many of Windows types were. I submitted QC reports on the subject. The declarations have been improved a little. I am surprised that you think that a thread ID should be stored in a `HANDLE`.

Comment: Yes! Then people would not use `THandle` for that which `LoadLibrary` returns, and so on and so on. The Windows API units should declare `HWND` like this: `HWND = type THandle`. And so on. See [`STRICT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383681.aspx).

Comment: I do not think "it should be stored as" anything. I am just fine with it being declared in any way that practically work until it brings practical negative consequences.  Of your MSDN link, "HANDLE 
A handle to an object." == HANDLE type is some abstract token denoting some object. "This type is declared in WinNT.h as follows" we found it convenient in our documentation to declare it as follows. Compare it with material declaration of "INT 
A 32-bit signed integer. The range is -2147483648 through 2147483647 decimal." HANDLE is abstract type.

Comment: @Arioch'The `HANDLE` is better described as an opaque type. It's absolutely not abstract. If I have a `HANDLE` returned from `CreateFile` that is very definitely not abstract. The implementation is hidden from me. It is opaque. It is an opaque pointer. You stuff it in a `LongWord` if you prefer. Your call.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Great! Now how could we enable STRICT in Delphi 2007 and write code for Win16 and Win64 ? // so perhaps you may complain that Delphi 2007 (or Delphi 7? or Delphi 2?) did not declared TThreadID = **type** xxx. That I would agree upon. (though as we saw it does not work in case of strings). However as long as each kind of handle - abstract ID having no material sense outside of windows DLLs - is not separated from any other type of handle - another abstract ID - I see little practical sense in being terrified by yet one more abstract ID of threads not being isolated.

Comment: @Arioch'The the writer of that library did consider FPC and Win64 as I saw in the source but no mention of what Delphi versions was the writer writing for. It was last copyrighted in 2009.

Comment: @Arioch I'm lost by that comment. I don't understand. I think I've said all I want to on this topic. I guess we don't agree.

Comment: If it is opaque pointer, then I can copy few megabytes, and back up the object pointed by that pointer for future use ? Also why handle HFILE is not a pointer ? it is handle too. Bogus, bogus is Windows typesystem. I fail to see the difference between your "opaque" and my "abstract". It both mean the same - you have to take it and pass it by intact without trying to get into implementation details. Okay, I have some troubles with inet. It only works few seconds after restarting my router. So I quit.

Comment: @arioch no, you cannot do that and there is no HFILE

Comment: There is where? In your link there is HFILE and is named "handle to..." so by your logic must have been an opaque pointer to some place in files table

Comment: @Arioch HFILE is from 16 bit OpenFile. So, in my eyes it does not exist! CreateFile returns HANDLE.

Comment: I guess I was wasting my time by answering the question that you asked. Why did you accept a non-answer?! You might personally choose to use that library, but surely you ought to accept an answer that actually answers the question that you asked. Please don't mix up the answer to the question that you asked with the solution to your problem. They are frequently different.

Answer (score 2):

I'm the author of BeRoXM. BeRoXM is since few months compatible with newer Delphi and FPC Versions.

But may I just ask, why did not you contact me directly by email? My email address can be found right at the beginning of the BeRoXM.pas file in a code comment.

Comment: +1 for your library update. Seems it's working in newer versions of Delphi.. Cheers!

Comment: Beacause contacting you by email does not give SO rep points! :)

Answer (score 0):

> without using DLLs

Without using, or without deploying ? You can have the DLL inside the application, unpack it to the temporary folder and load from it.

> And the debugger says:

The debugger only works when the program is already running. Since you could not compile, that is the compiler saying.

> Types of actual and formal var parameters must be identical
>
> So could you please tell me how I can fix this error?

1. You should understand when the function been used. There may be several functions named "BeginThread". You have to nail the one that compiler really wants to use. Usually Ctrl+Click is enough to find it, though sometimes IDE goes nuts.
2. You should copy the declaration of that function here for us.
3. You should find and copy the declarations of all the parameters you try to feed into the function. Here they are `BeRoXMThreadProc, self, ThreadID`.
4. You would have to compare data types that  declared for the parameters inside "BeginThread" declaration (those are called formal ones) and used in the place you try to call the function (those are called actual ones). And make them match each other.

This may be the declaration of the function you try to call

- http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/System.BeginThread
- http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/system/tthreadfunc.html

But maybe it is not - as said above, There may be several functions named "BeginThread".

PS: though I put those links above, you'd better copy into your question the actual functions and types declarations from your sources. StackOverflow tries to be self-dependent site, where all required data is already present in question without external links, that can go offline or 404 in future.

Comment: Why all the complexity? It's really not that hard.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan it is not hard when you know what the error is and how to fix it. But when you don't you have to have a step by step guide. Or a something debugging your program for you. On an unrelated note, can you drop mail to documentation@EMBT ? they forgot Delphi declaration at http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/System.TThreadFunc I don't have my mail here, can you drop them a note

Comment: We do know what the error is, and it's one that is always trivial to understand

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I do not, I didn't downloaded the code. And - if this error is trivial, then why you don't teach topicstarter how to fix it ?

Comment: Wellm I did exactly that

Comment: @DavidHeffernan No, you fixed it for her, without telling how and why. You did not taught he to get the fish, you just gave her a free one, but as the fish would be eaten, she would be helplessly hungry as before

Comment: **"Find me a library"** isnt a felony, really.

Comment: @FreeConsulting not a felony, just an offtopic on SO.

Comment: If it constitutes the whole question - yes, but being open for the other existing solution in no way is an off-topic.

Comment: @FreeConsulting and that "other part" was answered. I just noted that the q was close. PS. actually, to be "open for other sugegstions" does not require asking for them explicitly

Comment: I don't get it. This Q is pretty good, why in the Wirth sake, it should be closed? Your edit make this Q to be less inviting the other solutions than the original version.

Comment: @FreeConsulting who forces you to close this question ?

Comment: I accidentally omitted "get" in "I don't get it", sorry.

Comment: @FreeConsulting **You** think that this question should be closed and ask **me** about it. You claim that just **adding two tags** makes question "less inviting" (I don't want to dispute if that is good or bad per se). I don't get your points too.

Comment: I never wanted to close anything, as I said, this Q is pretty good. But was better when OP was open for the other solutions.

Comment: @FreeConsulting you keep talking about closing the question, then it suddenly was not what you want. Then just why repeating it over and over? /// She still is open.  I repeat:  to be "open for other sugegstions" does not require asking for them explicitly

Comment: Citing: *"I just noted that the q was close"*.

Comment: @FreeConsulting in English "close" == "near" and it was near offtopic

Comment: Finally back to topic. I do not agree with that, sorry.